# Order of sentence and using 's

Tags: possessives

> ...absolutely 100% our doing, not the Restaurant's.

or

> ...absolutely 100% our doing, not the Restaurants.

The first one feels right, but looks a little odd.

I think it's the first, because you would say

> ...the Restaurant's doing.

even thought it might not look right.  And, I think you have to show possession, right?

Can someone clarify, and hopefully point me to a resource?

Comment: "...the Restaurant's doing." --This is exactly the way to figure out what is correct. Add the missing/implied word(s) and see what would be correct. And I'm with Shinto Sherlock: no capitalization of restaurant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...absolutely 100% our doing, not the
>   Restaurant's.
>
> or
>
> ...absolutely 100% our doing, not the
>   Restaurants.
>
> The first one feels right, but looks a
>   little odd.

It doesn't look in the slightest bit odd to me. The only odd thing there is the capital letter in Restaurant. Anyway, the top one is the correct answer.

> Can someone clarify, and hopefully point me to a resource?

Gosh, I don't have any resources except my own wild guesses.

Comment: I'd concur with this; there needs to be a possessive in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  I do know that Restaurant should be restaurant, but I'm going to argue (not very loudly) that in my context it shows an emphasis that fits in with the sentence and paragraph as a whole.